# Can't select/highlight text in dynamic div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div whose innerHTML is dynamically updated (think of it like a chat room where a new paragraph is appended for each new message).

Problem is, right now users can't select/highlight text, because the selection gets altered every time the div updates.  Sometimes it will be cleared out, and other times it will select the entire div.

Best illustrated through this snippet:

```js
function modify(){
  document.getElementById('panel').innerHTML += "<p>Another message.  Try to highlight me.</p>";
}

setInterval(modify, 500);
```

```css
.highlightable {  
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;  
  user-select: text;            
}
```

```html
<div id='panel' class='highlightable'>
  
</div>
```

I've tried adding css user-select:text but no luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Issue**

By manipulating the same `innerHTML` every time, each call to `modify()` is *re-writing* the contents of `panel`. The item you've highlighted is deleted and re-created, thus why it loses its highlight.

**The Solution**

A better way to do this would be to *create a new element* for each iteration and *append it* to the panel instead. Using this method you won't have to worry about re-writing existing content, therefore your highlight will remain.

```js
function modify(){
  var panel = document.getElementById('panel');

  //Create a new <p> element
  var newP = document.createElement('p');

  //Set its content
  newP.innerHTML = 'Another message.  Try to highlight me.';

  //Add it to panel
  panel.appendChild(newP);
}

setInterval(modify, 500);
```

```css
.highlightable {  
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;  
  user-select: text;            
}
```

```html
<div id='panel' class='highlightable'>
  
</div>
```

Comment: thanks these properties worked like a charm

 -webkit-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;  
  user-select: text;